# Using google account for authentication other than App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Is it possible to use Google Accounts for authentication in your application if you not use App Engine? Is this service is only for those applications which run in GAE?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use Google accounts for authentication:

[OpenID API Documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html)

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow is a good example.
You can use OpenID provided by Google to sign in.

Comment: This was in my mind too. But I was thinking if there is another way. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can also download the chromium os source and compile pam_google.

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for OAuth, and more precisely 3-legged OAuth.

[Google supports the OAuth protocol for authorizing web applications accessing their users' Google services.](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth.html)

Your app will need to be registered with Google, but the process is relatively painless.

Have fun :)

J

Comment: OAuth is not an authentication protocol, it is an authorization delegation protocol.